# How many times is the copy constructor is called in this C++ snippet?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

In this question we have to find how many times a copy-constructor is called, 
according to me its 5 but answer is 7. how is that happening?

```
Widget  f(Widget  u)
{
    Widget v(u);
    Widget w = v;
    return w;
}
int main()
{
    Widget x;
    Widget y = f(f(x));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it in a debugger and trace every step? In addition to that, please post a minimum but complete definition of Widget.

Comment: Can you say which 5 you found so we can more easily tell you which ones you missed? (note that the exact number depends on copy elision, move semantics, etc)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the copy-constructor, and when it hits look at the call-stack to see where it originates from. Then simply count the number times the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Isn't it just 3 for each `f(x)` call + 1 for `y` assignment? You call the function by value and do two copies inside.

Comment: according to me, 1st- V(U) step, second widget w=v; for once, so total 4 and at last widget y step. so total 5. which one i missed?

Comment: You pass the parameter to the function by value - so a copy is made. If you would have used function like `f(Widget& u)` you would get 5 copies.

Comment: ohk.now i get that. thank you. :-)

Comment: No problem. Let me turn that into an answer.

Comment: note: the answer is different in C++03 than C++11, unless Widget is non-movable; which version are you asking about?

Comment: i was asking about c++11

Comment: Answer depends on C++ flavour and optimization level. It looks like a job interview test, a bad one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

+1 - assignment `Widget y = f(f(x))`

**+2 - calling the function `f()` twice, passing the parameter by value and not by reference.**

+2 - copy `v(u)` called twice

+2 - copy-initialization `Widget w = v` called twice

Makes 7.

Note that it is true for certain compilers under certain settings. The other answers are correct as well, my explains why the result COULD be 7, which you could obtain, for example, under `bcc32`.

Comment: I think this one is missing the copy created by `f` when the function runs the `return` statement. This answer seems incorrect. Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/34351914/4594973

Comment: Shouldn't return value optimization take care of that?

Comment: Read my post and look specifically at the `fno-elide-constructors` flag-based stuff.

Comment: Indeed you're right for g++. Yet the answer should be 7, and it is under certain compilers. For 7, find a e.x. bcc32 compiler. 7 copies are made. The question is not that good, as it not specifies the environment.

Comment: I agree the question is not great, but saying that the answer "should be 7" still seems incorrect to me. The 7 is a consequence of some optimizations being made by your specific compiler, but if we go down this road, we'll never get a "correct" answer b/c there're many different compilers. You need to tell your compiler to *not* optimize things like that (like I did with `g++`) to then see all of the copy ctor calls.

Comment: Well, 'should be 7' was the mystery to start with - it was in the original question. It was not that easy to recreate the possible environment for such starting point. `bcc32` is really outdated.

Answer (score 2):

With disabled copy-elision and move there is:

1) `Widget y = f(f(x));`

And there are 4 calls to copy constructor in `f` function.

1) `u` is passed by value.

2) `v` is copy-initialized from `u`.

3) `w` is copy-initialized from `v`.

4) `w` is copied on return.

So, there are actually 9 calls.

With enabled copy-elision there are 5 calls on gcc/clang.

Comment: The OP got 7 - I assume he counted that in a static variable, or output in the constructor. So we see copy elision in action here. I guess it is the copy during return, that is elided here.

Answer (score 1):

> how many times a copy-constructor is called, according to me its 5 but
>   answer is 7. how is that happening?

After updating your code snippet to code that actually works (see bottom), you can see the following output (code in `test.cpp`):

```
➜  /tmp g++ -o test -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./test
default ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
```

We just need to see how a *single* function call works. For that we have:

```
Widget  f(Widget  u)
{
        Widget v(u);
        Widget w = v;
        return w;
}

y = f(x)
```

The copy ctor gets invoked when:

- sending `x` into `f`, by value
- creating `v` from `u` in `f`
- assigning `v` into `w` in `f`
- returning `w` from `f`
- assigning `f`'s return value to `y`

So, for every call of `f` we need to use the copy ctor `4` times, and since `f` gets called twice you already have `+8` copy ctor calls, `+1` for the final assignment in `y`, totaling `9`.

### But *why* do we only see 5 in the output above?

The answer is: optimizations

GCC is removing some copying operations through optimizations. We can see all of them if we build it using the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag:

```
➜  /tmp  g++ -fno-elide-constructors -o -std=c++11 test test.cpp && ./test
def ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
```

This tells GCC to *not* perform the optimizations seen in our previous build, which shows all the copy constructor invocations below the default constructor used for `x`.

### Code Snippet Used

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Widget {

public:
        Widget() { cout << "def ctor" << endl; }
        Widget(const Widget &other) { cout << "copy ctor" << endl; }
};

Widget  f(Widget u)
{
        Widget v(u);
        Widget w = v;
        return w;
}

int main()
{
        Widget x;
        Widget y = f(f(x));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, i was also having same problem but i think some version issue is there as pointed by M.M  
"note: the answer is different in C++03 than C++11, unless Widget is non-movable; which version are you asking about?"

Comment: @BijonGuha: Using the `-std=c++11` flag shows no difference and is what you stated you were using in a comment, so why are you still saying it's a "version difference"? My post is accurate based on your info.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Since i am just a beginner i dont have that much idea. even i dont know what does this means " -std=c++11 " . But when i ran your code in my compiler i am getting 5. Seriously i am also totally confused what is happening.

Comment: Let me know if you have a specific question about something I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Can the down voter explain his/her reasoning for the down vote?

Comment: @BijonGuha: The `-std=c++11` tells the compiler to use `C++ 11` features. The reason you're getting 5 in *your compiler* (we don't know what you're using) is the optimizations I explained previously. If your compiler has a flag to not perform these optimizations, then you should try that and see. But again, different compilers optimize differently. My response aims to give the "true" number by preventing the compiler optimizations in the first place, showing all of the copy ctor calls that you would *actually* get if they were not getting automatically optimized for you without your knowledge.